# Controllers and Directives in Angular + RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cXxCqK22AFgKOpwPkJpX?p=preview) I have a sample code running Angular + Angular UI Router + RequireJS. There are two pages, each with a corresponding controller. If you click on View 1, you should see a page that contains a directive.

When the page loads it throws the following exception:

> Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined at at my-ctrl-1.js:3

meaning that `app` is undefined in `my-ctrl-1.js` even though I'm returning it in `app.js`. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
 <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href ui-sref="view1">View 1</a></li>
    <li><a href ui-sref="view2">View 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ui-view></div>
```

main.js

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        'domReady': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require-domReady/2.0.1/domReady',
        'angular': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min',
        "uiRouter": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router"
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'uiRouter':{
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    },

    deps: [
        'start'
    ]
});
```

start.js

```
define([
    'require',
    'angular',
    'app',
    'routes'
], function (require, angular) {
    'use strict';
    require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
});
```

app.js

```
define([
    'angular',
    'uiRouter',
    'my-ctrl-1',
    'my-ctrl-2',
    'my-dir-1'
], function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    console.log("app loaded");
    return angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
});
```

my-ctrl-1.js

```
define(['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
      $scope.hello = "Hello1: ";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a circular dependency between `app.js` and `my-ctrl-1.js`. When RequireJS encounters a circular dependency, the references it passes to the modules' factories are going to be `undefined`. There are many ways to solve the issue. One simple way that would work with the code you show could be to change `my-ctrl-1.js` to:

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (app) {
        app.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
          $scope.hello = "Hello1: ";
        });
    };
});
```

And in `app.js`:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'my-ctrl-1',
    'my-ctrl-2',
    'my-dir-1',
    'uiRouter',
], function (angular, ctrl1) {
    'use strict';
    console.log("app loaded");
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
    ctrl1(app);
    return app;
});
```

Presumably, you'll have to do the same thing with your other controler.

The [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) has a section on the topic of circular dependencies and other methods to handle them.

Comment: thanks for the info. I have many controllers in my application and I would have to list all of them in app.js, shouldn't I break the circular dependency by removing `my-ctrl-1` from `app.js` and adding it to `routes.js` ?

Comment: With the code you currently have, it looks like it should work. There are many ways to solve the issue, some which may be more convenient than others.

Comment: Thanks, it worked adding the dependencies in route.js. This is the working code http://plnkr.co/edit/WEi65QQKL4ec3x88qTKj?p=preview